# Syntax error during creation of trigger on mySQL 10.3.17-MariaDB-log version

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb-10.3

I'm trying to add a trigger that should automatically update a datetime column only if is not present a SQL variable. The trigger code is the following

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER update_sync_date
BEFORE UPDATE ON posts
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF @disable_sync_date_update IS NULL OR @disable_sync_date_update <> 1 THEN
        SET new.sync_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    END IF
END|
delimiter ;
```

The error that I recieve is

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF
END' at line 7
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Every statement must be terminated..

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, here is the correct code:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER update_sync_date
BEFORE UPDATE ON posts
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF @disable_sync_date_update IS NULL OR @disable_sync_date_update <> 1 THEN
        SET new.sync_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    END IF;
END|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: As a matter of interest what is @disable_sync_date_update and where is it set?

Comment: is a personal SQL variable that I set to 1 if I don't want that the trigger update the column sync_date with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP